# Is it possible to solve this nonlinear first order ODE using elementary methods?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a trick, such as substitution or otherwise to solve this ode using elementary methods?

$$
  y = \left(y'\right)^3 y^2 + 2 x y'
$$

Maple says this is 1st order with linear symmetries. Tracing it, is seems to be using Lie methods which I do not know too well yet or something it calls `1st order, parametric methods` which I also did not study.

I wonder if someone can see a simpler method to solve this? This is my attempt.

First solved for $y'$. This gives 3 ode's. Two of them are complex, so I threw these away as I am looking for real solution $y(x)$. The third one turned out to be isobaric. So I solved it using substitution as normally is done. But this gives integral which can't be solved. So my final solution was not verified by Maple and it is too complicated.

Maple gives these solutions (I show only the real ones). The first three solutions below are singular solutions. So the last two ones below is what I am interested in finding for now.

\begin{align*}
y \! \left(x \right) &= 
-\frac{2 2^{\frac{1}{4}} 3^{\frac{1}{4}} \left(-x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{3}\\
 y \! \left(x \right) &= 
\frac{2 2^{\frac{1}{4}} 3^{\frac{1}{4}} \left(-x^{3}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}}{3}\\
y(x) &=0\\
y \! \left(x \right) &= \sqrt{c_1^{3}+2 c_1 x}\\
y \! \left(x \right) &= -\sqrt{c_1^{3}+2 c_1 x}
\end{align*}

Is it possible to solve this ode, without using Lie symmetry methods using something more basic. most likely some smart substitution?

Just looking for hint.

Comment: Should it be ...$+2xy'$??

Comment: @Chrystomath thanks. Sorry it was a typo. corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $u=y^2$, then
$$
u=u'x+\frac{u'^3}8
$$
is a Clairaut equation with solution family
$$
u=Cx+\frac{C^3}8=2cx+c^3~~~~(C=2c)
$$
and a singular curve $$
0=x+\frac{3u'^2}8\implies u=u'x-\frac{u'x}3=\pm\frac{2x}{3}\sqrt{-\frac{8x}{3}}
$$
which is defined for $x\le0$.

Comment: Thanks. But how did you find this transformation? Is there a hint to detect it? I am writing this in a program.  Or was it just trial and error? or is there a pattern you looked for that made you try this?

Comment: Multiplying the ODE by $y(x)$ we get $y^2 = (y y')^3+2xy y'$ and $y y'=\frac 12(y^2)'$...

Comment: If you look at it, it has a rather typical pattern for Clairaut DE, $y=axy'+f(y,y')$. But not every equation with this pattern is Clairaut, this is a rather unstable situation, every small change will make this a more general problem.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes, I tried Clairaute and dAlembert. But in these the form is  $y=x f(y') + g(y')$ so the functions $f(y'),g(y')$ are functions of $y'$ only and not of $y',y$. That is why it failed the check. But thanks. The hard part is that I am doing this in a program, and so need an algorithm or a pattern to detect and hard to just try different substitutions like we do by hand. Will try to see if I can add a check for this.

Answer (score 1):

See Kamke, E. Differentialgleichungen, Lösungsmethoden und Lösungen...$\quad$ 1.541.

Let $u(y)=1/y'$, $x=x(y)$.

We diff(%,y) and get
$$(yu'-u)(2y+u^3)=0$$
Then solutions is
$$y^2=2Cx+C^3$$
and
$$32x^3+27y^4=0$$